# Eliminar un elemento de una "lista"

Tags: c, lista

Buenas,

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con punteros en C y me ha surgido una duda respecto a un algoritmo que estoy implementando que hace uso extenso de `malloc`, `realloc` y `free`, este es el código:

*List.h*

```
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_

typedef struct {
    int    Count;
    void **Elements;
} List;

List *list_new();
void  list_insert(List *l, void *elem);
void *list_getelem(List *l, int offset);
void  list_removeoffset(List *l, int elem);
void  list_free(List *l);
int   list_get_count(List *l);

#endif
```

*List.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "List.h"

List *list_new() {
    List *ptr = malloc(sizeof(List));
    ptr->Elements = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    ptr->Count = 0;
    return (ptr) ? ptr : NULL;
}
void list_insert(List *l, void *elem) {
    if (l->Count == 0) 
        l->Elements = realloc(l->Elements, sizeof(void*));
    else 
        l->Elements = realloc(l->Elements, (sizeof(void*) * l->Count));
    l->Elements[l->Count] = elem;
    l->Count++;
}
void *list_getelem(List *l, int offset) {
    if (offset < 0 || offset >= l->Count) return NULL;
    return l->Elements[offset];
}
void list_removeoffset(List *l, int elem) {
    if (elem < 0 || elem >= l->Count) return;
    l->Elements[elem] = NULL; 
    l->Count--; 
    l->Elements = realloc(l->Elements, sizeof(void*) * l->Count);   
}
void list_free(List *l) {
    if (l) {
        free(l->Elements); free(l);
    }
}
int list_get_count(List *l) {
    return l->Count;
}
```

Mi problema surge dentro de la declaración del método `list_removeoffset(...)` no consigo eliminar un elemento en una posición `offset` en el array de punteros.

`main()`:

```
List *MyList = list_new();

list_insert(MyList, (int*)3416); printf("List Count Now: %d\n", list_get_count(MyList));
list_insert(MyList, (char*)"hello world"); printf("List Count Now: %d\n", list_get_count(MyList));
list_insert(MyList, (int*)5); printf("List Count Now: %d\n", list_get_count(MyList));
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo con el código anterior:

```
List Count Now: 1
List Count Now: 2
List Count Now: 3
Element at position 1: hello world
```

Efectivamente funciona, pero al intentar con el siguiente código para remover los elementos:

```
list_removeoffset(MyList, 1); // Intento remover el elemento en la posicion 1.
```

Al parecer se elimina, pero, de la misma forma libera la memoria de los demás elementos que esten luego de este y me muestra por resultado `0`.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar o liberar sólo un elemento y no todos los que estan a partir de este?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada, tu implementación es bastante ineficiente en tiempo computacional por la cantidad de `realloc` que estás utilizando. Ten en cuenta que en el peor caso `realloc` copia bloques de memoria. Con lo cual, una operación que en una lista enlazada es `O(1)` en tu lista termina siendo `O(n)`. Te recomiendo mantener un tamaño físico y uno lógico en tu lista y solamente redimensionar el vector "hacia arriba" cuando el tamaño lógico está muy próximo al físico y "hacia abajo" cuando el tamaño lógico es muy pequeño con respecto al físico.

Pasando a tu pregunta, `realloc` reduce el tamaño del bloque de memoria que utiliza pero sólo eso. Es tu responsabilidad como implementador "adelantar" los elementos de la lista que quedan antes del espacio liberado. Esquemáticamente, sucede algo así:

Vector original:

```
------------------------
0: ptr to 3416
1: ptr to "hello world"
2: ptr to 5
------------------------
```

Después de reasignar `l->Count` y `l->Elements[1]`:

```
------------------------
0: ptr to 3416
1: NULL
2: ptr to 5
------------------------
```

Después del `realloc`:

```
------------------------
0: ptr to 3416
1: NULL
------------------------
2: ptr to 5 <<< Fuera del bloque, y la memoria ya no le pertenece a tu programa
```

En definitiva, lo que sucede no es que se liberan todos los datos del vector a partir del que estás borrando sino que se pierde el último. En tu caso en particular, como el vector tiene sólo tres elementos, el último elemento es también "todos los elementos a partir del borrado".

Lo que deberías hacer es, en lugar de asignar `NULL` a `Elements[1]`, copiarle el contenido de `Elements[2]` (y de `[3]` a `[2]`, de `[4]` a `[3]` y así sucesivamente). De esta manera, antes del `realloc` te quedaría el vector así:

```
------------------------
0: ptr to 3416
1: ptr to 5 <<< Copiado de [2]
2: ptr to 5
------------------------
```

Y luego del `realloc`:

```
------------------------
0: ptr to 3416
1: ptr to 5
------------------------
2: ptr to 5
```

Comment: Y, no debería asignar `NULL` al último valor en el vector?

Comment: No es estrictamente necesario, porque esa memoria se libera y deja de pertenecer a tu programa. Quedará rellena con "basura" para el próximo que la quiera usar.

Comment: En otras palabras, `realloc` libera la memoria que mi programa utilizó en algún momento?

Comment: Usar `realloc` es parecido a usar `malloc` para generar un nuevo bloque más grande / chico, `memcpy` para copiar el contenido al nuevo bloque y `free` para liberar el bloque original. La diferencia es que `realloc` tiene la "inteligencia" para agrandar / achicar el mismo bloque cuando esto es posible y así evitar la copia. Pero los datos que eran parte del bloque original y quedaron fuera al hacer `realloc` quedan liberados como si hubieras llamado `free` sobre esa porción solamente.

Answer (score 1):

Al hacer la eliminación estás poniendo el elemento `elem` a NULL y luego haces realloc, con lo que se pierde el último elemento.
Esto es lo que pasa con `list_removeoffset(MyList, 1);`

```
Count = 3                                 Count = 2
Elem 0 : (void*) 3416                     (void*) 3416
Elem 1 : (void*) "hello world"   =====>   (void*) NULL
Elem 2 : (void*) 5
```

Y esto es lo que quieres obtener :

```
Count = 3                                 Count = 2
Elem 0 : (void*) 3416                     (void*) 3416
Elem 1 : (void*) "hello world"   =====>   (void*) 5
Elem 2 : (void*) 5
```

Para ello tienes que reasignar todos los elementos desde `elem+1` hasta el final una posición inferior del array :

```
void list_removeoffset(List *l, int elem) {
    int i;
    if (elem < 0 || elem >= l->Count) return;
    --(l->Count);
    for( i=elem; i<l->Count; ++i ) {
      l->Elements[i] = l->Elements[i+1];
    }
    l->Elements = realloc(l->Elements, sizeof(void*) * l->Count);   
}
```

Nótese que `list_insert` tiene un error. Cuando Count vale 1 se reserva tamaño para un elemento pero habría que reservar para dos; 1 para el que ya hay y otro para el nuevo. Lo mismo pasa para valores mayores.
Lo correcto sería :

```
void list_insert(List *l, void *elem) {
    l->Elements = realloc(l->Elements, sizeof(void*)*(l->Count+1));
    l->Elements[l->Count] = elem;
    ++l->Count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás haciendo un realloc a un tamaño menor. Esta función de C es de bajo nivel y no tiene en cuenta los "null", por lo que simplemente te está eliminando cosas del final del array. Por cierto, reducir el tamaño no tiene un comportamiento definido, por lo que también podría quitar los elementos del principio.

Lo que tú quieres lograr, que es usar la memoria justa, se consigue con listas enlazadas. Lo único malo es que iterar sobre ellas es más lento al no estar en posiciones contiguas de memoria (fallos de caché). Pero se pueden hacer aproximaciones más "espectaculares" que reservan la memoria por bloques.

Comment: Reducir el tamaño sí tiene un comportamiento definido, véase : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html